# iOS Safari browser website issue (no height?)

Tags: css

I have a gallery slideshow, work in most browser, but not on iOS Safari browser. I use css prefixes, but no luck. I think, the height of image container is zero, but I'm not sure, I don't testing on PC (windows). Would someone be willing to see the website? https://poplart.hu/hu/portfolio/Tesco_Finest

The images don't show, only gray background.

Expected:
[image: expexted]

Actual:
[image: actual]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gallery has zero-height, `height: 100%;` doesn't do what you expected. Use 100vh instead.

```
.h100, #gallery .slideshow, #gallery .slidewrap, .galleryWrap, #galleryView, #galleryView section.read, gallery, #gallery, .slideshow .view-area {
    height: 100vh;
}
```